# How to find height and width of Viewgroup Android

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I was able to use getDisplayHeight() / getDisplayWidth(), but that gives me the width and height of the workspace.

I want to get the exact height and width of the viewgroup on the home screen of
an android device.

Answer (score 0):

```
Point display = new Point();
getWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(display);
int width = display.x
int height = displ
```

I'm not 100% clear if that's what you're looking for... I don't know what you meant by "ViewGroup on the homescreen". What I just posted will give you the exact height and width of the screen, in pixels. If you want the height or width of a View just call getHeight() or getWidth();.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
int height = tv.getHeight();
int width = tv.getWidth();
```